# Header adds up URL piece on every click

Tags: php

I have the update page on admin panel where you can update information for each user and I have an "activate" button there which simply changes the text in the MySQL database row named "status". Every time I click on the activate button it redirects to another PHP file named "activate.php", here is the script:

```
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

$status = 'active';
$id = $_GET['userid'] ?: '';

$SQL = $conn->prepare("UPDATE register SET status=? WHERE id=?");
$SQL->bind_param('ss', $status, $id);
$SQL->execute();

header("Location: updateregistrations.php?userid=$id?activated");
```

Here is the problem: every time I click on activate button it goes through this file and gets me back to the users information edit page with "?activated" added in the URL, it changes status at first but when I click on the activate button again while "?activated" is still in the URL it doesn't work and instead it just adds up "?activated" in the URL, so like this: "?activated? activated? activated".

Comment: First of all, you should separate query strings with `&` not with multiple `?`. Can you show how u make the URL to redirect to this page?

Comment: <a href="activate.php?userid=<?php echo $_GET['userid'] ?>" class="activate" onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')">Activate</a>

Comment: The code you wrote set the status to `active` as it seems. But I don't get what is the problem with multiple `?activated`.

Comment: Well it doesn't work the second time I click on activate button while ?activated is in the url, it just adds ?activated like this: updateregistrations.php?userid=10?activated?activated?activated

Comment: What do you expect to happen when it is already changed to `active`?

Comment: You cannot append multiple query params with `?`.  The question mark is used only before the 1st query param, and all others are supposed to be added/separated by `&`. So, `?userid=$id?activated` is not valid anyway; it's supposed to be `?userid=$id&activated`. Also, we're missing your frontend part so this is just tapping in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like `?userid=$id&status=activated"`.  At the moment it's taking the value of `userid` as `$id?activated`.

The `&` separates the parameters and then you can use `$_GET['status']` to retrieve the value of they status.

Comment: I only add ?activated in the redirect header because then I can use jquery to trigger window.location.href.indexOf for SweetAlert2